# camscanner and cropping pages

Tags: scanner

I've got a camscanner (mustek mcs 500 A3 pro) which I use to scan books. The Ubuntu version I use is 16.04. The problem I face is that, although I have successfully installed the software that comes with the camscanner via wine, and although it works flawlessly, the scanner itself is not recognized by it or any scanning program like simplescan or xsane. In fact, it is recognized only by cheese, ie as a web camera, not as a scanner. I can use it with cheese but I lose all the benefits of the software provided by the manufacturer.

So, I'm looking for the following:

1. To have my camscanner recognized by Ubuntu,
2. to use it with the provided software, or
3. to use it with some other software as long as it provides the following features:

   - to be able to recognize and crop the text from the surroundings,
   - to be able to define the dimensions of the scanning area, for example A4 or A5,
   - to be able to set time lapses for taking snapshots of the pages (for instance every 5 seconds).

Cheese provides the last option (time lapses) but none of the others.

This scanner is essential to my work and it's a pain to have to use windows every time (that is very very frequently) I need it. I am desperate to find a way to make it work.

At least, I could compromise with a software that can crop pages, ie the borders of the text. That is, I would use cheese to scan the pages of a book (in jpeg or tiff)  and then, collectively, I would crop them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ScanTailor fills the gap. It is available under Ubuntu.
I saw a video on YouTube with a ipevo ziggi-hd document camera and  ScanTailor.
Looked very promising to me.

Comment: This is really just a comment at the moment. You need to explain how to install the application and how to use it to achieve what the question asks for